# how to run php action and javascript code on a same button

Tags: javascript, php, actionscript

```
<div id="askfriend">
      <form action="friend.php" method="post">
       <input type="submit" id="requestbutton" name="requestbutton2" value="Send Friend Request" style="margin-top:5%; margin-left:10%; height:50%;" onclick="change()"/>
       <input type="submit" id="cancelbutton" name="cancelbutton2" value="Cancel" disabled style="margin-top:5%; margin-left:10%; height:50%; width:30%;" onclick="changeback()"/>
      </form>
       <?php
        if(isset($_POST['requestbutton2']))
         {
          echo "clicked";
         }
       ?>
     </div>

<script>
  function change()
   {
    var elem=document.getElementById("requestbutton");
    var elem2=document.getElementById("cancelbutton");
    if(elem.value=="Send Friend Request")
     {
      elem.value="Friend Request Send";
      elem.disabled=true;
      elem2.disabled=false;
     }
   }
  function changeback()
   {
    var elem=document.getElementById("requestbutton");
    var elem2=document.getElementById("cancelbutton");
    if(elem2.value=="Cancel")
     {
      elem2.disabled=true;
      elem.value="Send Friend Request";
      elem.disabled=false;  
     }
   }
 </script>
```

when I click "Send Friend Request" button javascript code runs but the action code whatever I wrote inside php, for the same button does not run.
What's the solution?

Comment: I can help you with code, if you need. =)

Comment: What is the name of the file you posted?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use AJAX.
So, when you tap on a button, JavaScript will make an HTTP request to your backend.

```
$("your_element_id").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: success,
      dataType: dataType
    });
});
```

Use jQuery or something like that. Here's a good manual.

Comment: By the time Javascript is being used on a page, the PHP is long done running. You'll need to make a separate file (maybe ajax.php) and have the javascript send a call to that file in order to get your php function to run

Comment: Yeah, it's good idea to keep code clean in separate files.
I'm using something like `scripts`, `scripts\ajax`, so it's easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("your_element_id").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: success,
      dataType: dataType
    });
});
```

Use jQuery or something like that. [Here's](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) a good manual.